# How to fix java.lang.illegalargumentexception attempt to create merge event with null entity in this particular scenario?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have jsf 2.x web application that has layers of hibernate/spring data jpa in it for database transaction.

I have `Foo` java entity which as `Bar` as its property with `OneToOne` relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="FOO_ID", nullable=false)
    private UUID fooId;

    @OneToOne
    private Bar bar;

}
```

Both entity has its own table in DB. The table `Bar` has its primary key as `bar_id` and foreign key `foo_id`. I tried to delete a record from `Bar` table for a certain condition using a custom repository extends JpaRepository from spring data jpa.

I executed following statement and I thought it should do a job.

```
this.barRepository.delete(foo.getBarId());
```

However I ran into `java.lang.illegalargumentexception attempt to create merge event with null entity`. I read an article about it `null` is passed as an argument but I verified `foo.getBarId()` is not null via debugging. 
I am not sure what went wrong and how to correct it.

[Update]

I am sorry. I found my mistake. For `BarRepository` has wrong entity type.

```
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, UUID>
```

It should have been:

```
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, UUID>
```